# how to uninstall pip from /usr/local/bin/

Tags: linux, rhel, python, pip

we want to uninstall the pip that located on path - /usr/local/bin/pip

when we did `pip uninstall` we get

```
 /usr/local/bin/pip uninstall pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.cli.main'
```

while  `/usr/local/bin/pip` isn't a link

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin/pip
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 225 Feb 11 11:37 /usr/local/bin/pip
```

so from where `which` command know the `pip` path?

second how to remove `pip` on path `/usr/local/bin/pip` completely ?

Comment: Could you first tell us how it went installed ? I mean via some package manager ? as a dependency ?

Comment: well - this is very old machine - so I not know

Comment: What is (are) already installed package managers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what distro you're currently running, but most of the time `pip` is installed (if not done from source) through a `python3-pip` package that ships with the distro at `/usr/bin/pip3` or `/usr/bin/pip`.

A quick look around [pkgs.org](https://pkgs.org/search/?q=%2Fusr%2Flocal%2Fbin%2Fpip) tells me that either you are running FreeBSD or have it installed from another source

For the first one, you need to find and delete the package (`pkg remove`). And for the last one, you **might** (don't quote me on this) be safe just deleting it out as it might not be linked to anything else